# vb6 ADODB.stream doesn't exist. .what shall i do?

Tags: vb6, adodb

ADODB.Stream doesn't exist in my Visual Basic 6. . I searched everywhere in the objects browser. Is there any method or installation so that i could provide it???

thanks guys

Comment: Your Windows version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Projects>References>Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library.
2. Then go to form and type the code.

   It should come up as Intellisense.

Comment: yeah...i just did that and it worked. thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for "ADODB" when the library isn't called that at all.  Normal language usage would just call this "ADO" but the Web is full of cargo-culters.  Why there is an "ADODB" tag here at all escapes me.

Look for a version of "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects."  Usually 2.5 is a reasonable choice unless you have good reasons to target a new version of the interface - they all point to the same DLL.

This is a system library used from all kinds of languages.  It has nothing directly to do with VB6, and is part of Windows now (and has been for well over a decade).

Comment: slr, anyway, thanks and i did that already.. i didnt notice that i used activex data objects 2.0... for all those who helped me as well, thanks a lot:)